# How much the world would change if room-temperature superconductivity is dicovered?

Tags: near-future, futurology

In what ways the world would change?

Should we expect table-top quantum computers, furniture without legs, high-speed cheap maglevs (or vacuum tube metros), lossless energy trasfer, high-capacity and/or compact energy storages, efficient fusion reactors, anything besides this?

Comment: This is a high-concept and massively broad. If you have questions about specific aspects we can help you but this is too broad.

Comment: Just because you discover room-temperature superconductivity doesn't mean that anything changes. I guess you are asking for a relatively cheap alloy of some kind that is superconductive, but currently you are not. Also room temperature is fine, but we might need a bit more so that things still work in the summer. I'm also sure a short google search can answer a lot of the questions you have and you should come back when you have more specific questions maybe or couldn't find something.

Comment: Apart from being to broad, since we don't really understand superconductivity, we not really on our way to develop RTSC materials soon

Answer (score 2):

It would finally make wind and solar a dominate source of power.

One of the biggest things limiting wind and solar is they don't produce power when we need power the most.       The advantage oil, coal, nuclear, and geo thermal have is they produce power on demand. Wind and solar produce when they feel like it.

This means we can't use them exclusively. We use them to supplement to reduce our need on other sources when they do produce but that's all.

Room temperature super conductivity would let us build stable efficient batteries. That would let us store energy and release it on demand.

Sure you could also give ball bearings a run for their money but the power thing seems like the big thing.

Comment: I do not disagree that this would be a step in the right direction, but I think there are more problems with for example solar power than just energy storage that need solving first. I also feel a bit sorry for you since you main thing, the energy storage, got editted into the question without comment or recognition.

Comment: @Raditz_35 That's how stackexchange works I don't need recognition. Just a good answer.